# Row not changes after I execute update command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to update my SQL Server table row.

Here is working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de2a2/2).

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE EventsCnfig
(
    Id int,
    InspectionId int,
    Event int
); 

CREATE TABLE Inspections
(
    Id int,
    IsRepaired Bit
);
```

Here is command that I use to update the row:

```
UPDATE EventsCnfig
SET InspectionId = 33, Event = 33
WHERE Id = 2;
```

After I execute update command and then execute select command on table `EventsCnfig` to check for changes I don't see any rows changes in `EventsCnfig` table.

Any idea why the `EventsCnfig` table does not change after I execute `UPDATE`  command?

Comment: How many rows does it report as affected?

Comment: Do you made a commit?

Comment: Do you have any rows with id 2?

Comment: How are you actually determining that the `UPDATE` failed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I check it with select command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `Commit` to update the changes

```
UPDATE EventsCnfig
SET InspectionId=33, Event=33
WHERE id=2; 
commit;
```

Comment: Unless there's more code involved than reported in the question, this isn't an answer.